Unable to deploy Flutter on Android
Flutter web and desktop apps are working perfectly fine, but not getting deployed on Android device.
Flutter 3.19.6 (latest)
Android Studio - Jellyfish 2023.3.1 (latest)
gradle 7.6.3
Java JDK - 19 (earlier did 22 & 21, but flutter/gradle says java 19 supported)
earlier i was getting only

but after updating SDK build tools, now getting:




Issue fixed by downloading SDK obselete

